# include a java-me jar with a blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to use the ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2.jar file. But on use time application create a error

```
Module 'ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Any 3rd party jar has to be preverified using the SDK's preverify tool.  Also, make sure that in Eclipse, you select the check box for the jar underneath the "Order and Export" tab when setting the build path (the same place where you add the jar)